# Passing a Variable to an Event in .NET

Tags: c#, events

For example I have a list of picture boxes that raise an event once the cursor hover over them.
Yet I need somehow not only to rise this event, but also to pass the "i" variable, so that I would know which picturebox has the cursor over it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
....
pbList.Add(new PictureBox());

pbList[i].MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.beeHideInfo);
                                            //// need to pass "i" here
}
```

and

```
    private void beeShowInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb_beeInfo.Text = "You are hovering over: "+beeList[i].name;
                                               /// need to get this "i"
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming pbList and beelist contain related items in the same order, you can do something like `beeList[ pbList.IndexOf(sender)  ].name`

Comment: Thanks,             PictureBox pbSender = (PictureBox)sender;
            lb_beeInfo.Text = beeList[pbList.IndexOf(pbSender)].name; worked!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass variables to an event.

Besides, the necessary variable has already been passed to you: `sender`.

`sender` is a reference to the object which raised the event. In your case, it's a reference to the PictureBox that raised the event.

Comment: +1, I agree that he already gets the object through sender, but can't he "pass variables" through evenargs (creating his own custom eventargs class, etc.)? I'm not saying he should for this case, just that it's possible.

Comment: (nitpicking; I understand you're going by the OP's example) Not exactly true.  You can create a custom EventArgs class, if you control the definition of the event's signature (i.e., you don't use one of the predefined, non-generic delegates).  Also, casting `sender` is one of those last-ditch things that should be avoided if other methods can be used.

Comment: @Richard: it's not his event. He can't control the EventArgs.

Answer (score 3):

The `object sender` parameter *is* the `PictureBox` sending the event. If you need to associate something with that object, you can use its `Tag` member:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    ....
    pbList.Add(new PictureBox() { Tag = beeList[i] });
    pbList[i].MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.beeHideInfo);
}
```

and

```
private void beeShowInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    Bee b = (Bee)pb.Tag;
    lb_beeInfo.Text = "You are hovering over: "+b.name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, PictureBox pbSender = (PictureBox)sender; lb_beeInfo.Text = beeList[pbList.IndexOf(pbSender)].name; worked!

Answer (score 1):

You could you do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    ...

    pbList.Add(new PictureBox());

    var index = i;
    pbList[i].MouseHover += 
        delegate
        {
            lb_beeInfo.Text = "You are hovering over: "+beeList[index].name;
        };
}
```

I.e. use an anonymous method.

As [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) says, there is an easier solution.

Comment: You should *reall* point out why you're using both `index` and `i` because even I didn't realize at first why.

Comment: To be honest, I am not 100% sure either. ReSharper warns that this is an "Access to modified closure" and as a resolution it suggests to copy the variable of the loop to a local variable. Could someone explain the reasons behind?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is use an anonymous function to explicitly pass the `PictureBox` or index instance into the handler.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
  ....
  var box = new PictureBox();
  pbList.Add(box);
  box.MouseHover += delegate { this.beeShowInfo(box); }
}

private void beeShowInfo(PictureBox box) 
{
   lb_beeInfo.Text = "You are hovering over: "+box.Name;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason this would be preferable to just casting `sender` to a `PictureBox` in the event handler?

Comment: @Gabe, The casting of `sender` is unsafe because the event handler is just another method and it can be called with a value of a completely different type. This pattern ensures that the value provided (when non-null) is indeed a `PictureBox` value.

Answer (score 1):

another way might be if you create a Custom Picture Box

```
class CustomPictureBox : PictureBox
{
  public int id;
  public CustomPictureBox(int ID)
 {
   id = ID;
 }

}
```

firt place a GLOBAL id to parent and each time if a CustomPicureBox is clicked get the ID
than everywhere you want to make changes to Clicked CustomPicutreBox test it

```
foreach(CustomPicutreBox i in Control.controls)
{
  if(i.ID == sender.ID)
  doWhatEveryYouWant(); 
}
}
```